# Unable to get attribute value from an ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, carrierwave

Trying to get a value from a object isn't working out.

```
  class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description,
                  :file,
                  :file_cache
  belongs_to :attachable,
             :polymorphic => true
  mount_uploader :file, AssetUploader
```

In console

```
  profile = Profile.first

  Profile Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `profiles`.* FROM `profiles` LIMIT 1 etc
```

profile.assets.inspect

```
Asset Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `assets`.* FROM `assets` WHERE `assets`.`attachable_id` = 1 AND `assets`.`attachable_type` = 'Profile'
 => "[#<Asset id: 1, description: nil, file: \"fa731ee80a.jpg\", attachable_id: 1, attachable_type: \"Profile\", created_at: \"2012-01-30 00:29:21\", updated_at: \"2012-02-07 22:13:17\">]"
```

How would I get the file attribute from this?
Tried numerous things but I just seem to be unable to figure it out

```
profile = Profile.first then profile.assets.first.file works
```

BUT

```
profile = Profile.where(:user_id => 2 ) then profile.assets.first.file returns a NoMethodError: undefined method `assets' for #<#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer: `profile.assets.first.file`

Actual answer: Your `profile` model should have a `has_one :asset, :as => :attachable` if each profile will only have one attached file, but it seems that you have a `has_many`.

**Update**

Try:

```
profile = User.find(2).profile
profile.assets
```

Or:

```
profile = Profile.where(:user_id => 2).first
profile.assets
```

Comment: profile = Profile.first then profile.assets.first.file works BUT profile = Profile.where(:user_id => 2 ) then profile.assets.first.file returns a NoMethodError: undefined method `assets' for #<#<Class:0x007ff8ea845b80>:0x007ff8eccd22f0>  . Both user_id 1 and 2 have valid asset in the assets column of db, therefore this confusion.

Comment: Is there more than one profile with `user_id = 2`? `Profile.where(:user_id => 2).count > 1` ?

Comment: bricker: no that returns false, the data in db seems fine thats why I can't grasp this

Comment: Bricker, I see just like that.. thats more simple than I thought, only how would this apply to getting this value outputted in a partial _profiles.haml rendering @profiles using this code:       = image_tag @profile.user.assets.first.file_url(:search) rescue nil. Your answer is totally correct though. thx!

Answer (score 0):

Seems in _profiles.haml partial rendering @profiles

This seems to work

- @profile = User.find(profile.id).profile
  = image_tag @profile.assets.first.file_url(:search) rescue nil

Not shure if its very clean though but for now it will do